# Attribute patch in pinia store is working from one component, but not from another (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I've those two components using Nuxt 3.

The setActive method in component 1 changes the state of activeColor, but the cancelEdit method in component 2 does not.

Any idea why this is the case?

**Component 1**

Here the setActive method changes activeColor:

```
<template>
  <div class="f-button" @click="addColor">+ Add Color</div>
  {{ activeColor }}
  <div class="f-colors">
    <Color v-for="color in colors" :color="color" :edit="activeColor === color" @click="setActive(color)"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {useProjectStore} from "~/stores/projects";
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
import Color from "~/components/Color.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "ColorManagement",
  components: {Color},
  setup() {
    const projectStore = useProjectStore()
    const { getColors, getActiveColor } = storeToRefs(projectStore);
    return {
      projectStore,
      colors: getColors,
      activeColor: getActiveColor
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addColor() {
      ...
    },
    setActive(color) {
      this.projectStore.$patch({ activeColor: color })
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**Component 2**

Here the cancelEdit method doesn't change activeColor:

```
  <div class="f-color">

    <div class="f-color__actions" v-if="edit">
      <div class="f-color__action" @click="cancelEdit">
        <Cancel /><span>Cancel</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
import Cancel from "~/components/icons/Cancel.vue";
import {useProjectStore} from "~/stores/projects";
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Color",
  components: {Cancel},
  props: ["color","edit"],
  setup() {
    const projectStore = useProjectStore()
    const { activeColor } = storeToRefs(projectStore);
    return {
      projectStore,
      activeColor
    };
  },
  methods: {
    cancelEdit() {
      this.projectStore.$patch({ activeColor: false })
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    additionalData: '@use "@/assets/styles/_styles.scss" as *;'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    modules: ['@pinia/nuxt']
})
```

**Store**

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useProjectStore = defineStore({
  id: 'project',
  state: () => {
    return {
      project: {
        colors: [{ color: false, name: '' }]
      },
      activeColor: null
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getColors(state){
      return state.project.colors || [];
    },
    getActiveColor(state){
      return state.activeColor;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any console.errors? I just replicated your code and it is working.

Comment: @ArthurBorba No errors in console. My expectation is, that "false" is displayed below "+ Add Color" in component 1 when I click "Cancel" in component 2. Instead it keeps showing the color object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I got this correctly, the deal is this:

Your so called **Component 2** is the `<Color ...` component being used in **Component 1**, right?

When you trigger `cancelEdit` inside `Component 2` (aka `Color`) you are also triggering the logic from `setActive` due to this `<Color ...@click="setActive(color)"`...so your activeColor is set to `false` (from the `cancelEdit` method) but right after it is set to active again, got it?

To fix this (if you don't want to change your HTML structure) you can use events `stopPropagation` method inside the `cancelEdit`:

```
cancelEdit(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  this.projectStore.$patch({ activeColor: false })
}
```

[Event.stopPropagation() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)